# Download XML instead of open

Tags: javascript

I've got a page with a button that allows to download a XML file by address.
At the beginning the js code connected to the button was:

```
function downloadURI(uri, name) {
  window.location = uri;
}
```

But all browsers opened the file instead of download it. Then I've tried with this code:

```
function downloadURI(uri, name) {
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.download = name;
  link.href = uri;
  link.click();
}
```

It works for IE, Edge, Opera and Chrome, but not on firefox. Can anyone help me solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox doesn't like clicks on links that aren't in the document. So append the link to `document.body` (or whatever) prior to the `link.click` call (and then remove it afterward, perhaps after a small `setTimeout` delay), e.g.:

```
function downloadURI(uri, name) {
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.download = name;
  link.href = uri;
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  setTimeout(function() {
    documet.body.removeChild(link);
  }, 50);
}
```

If that doesn't work in your setup, the way I've done this reliably is to make what the user clicks a link rather than a button, and have the link target a hidden `iframe` by name, and have the response to the link request contain the `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=foo` header, which tells the browser to download rather than open.

Comment: Or just set an event listener for the click and remove it inside that event listener.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir: In my experience, that's too soon. The above will do it when the click's default action has already been initiated.